# Google spreadsheet: Cannot select pre-selected date in Date picker

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet, when having a cell formatted as date, or with a data validation set on date, a date picker appears when double clicking this cell.

If the cell is blank, the picker's date is pre-selected to today's date but I cannot select it. I need to first select an other date, open the picker again and then I can select today's date.

Does anyway know how I could select the highlighted date in the picker?

Comment: I believe it's a bug. I would submit a bug here - https://support.google.com/drive/?hl=en#ts=2624997. Go to > Contact  Us

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra just create a sheet, set a cell "data validation" to Date. Then try to select today's date. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems to have fixed this bug. I tried this morning and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the date picker for today, instead <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`;`, validated or formatted or not.

Comment: Good workaround. However, still, cannot select today is annoying.